# Python requests - SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')

Tags: python, python-requests

The below curl command works fine when executed from linux -

```
curl -w "\n" -k --cert ~/pace.crt --key ~/pace.key --header "Accept: application/json" "https://url" -X GET;
```

When I tried to fetch the response from the url using python requests, I get ssl error:

```py
certVal = ('location/pace.cert', 'location/pace.key')
methodName = 'GET'
urlLink = 'https://LinkToAdeviceConnectedToPC'
headersVal = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
res = requests.request(method=methodName, url=urlLink, headers=headersVal, cert=certVal)
```

Error:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: urllink (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I tried solutions suggested in the forums but didn't work.

Comment: What values are you passing to requests?  You only showed us variable names.

Comment: I have edited and added the values to the variables. Hope this would be sufficient.